# Why does writing to plist fail in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, swift3

I am trying to write the contents of an NSMutableDictionary to a plist in Swift 3.  This is the structure I used in Objective-C but it does not work in Swift.  When running the code below, it results in an error.  Does anyone have any idea what might be wrong here?

```
let array1 = "\(Int(Value1))"
let array2 = "\(Int(Value2))"

let paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.documentDirectory, .userDomainMask, true)
let plistpath = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: paths[0]).appendingPathComponent("myplist9.plist")!.absoluteString

let dictionary: NSMutableDictionary = ["String":"String"]
dictionary["Value 1"] = array1
dictionary["Value 2"] = array2

if dictionary.write(toFile: plistpath, atomically: false) {
    print("Success")
}
else {
    print("Error")
}
```

Comment: Why don't you simply use the URL related API to write the file? And be aware of literal "Optional(12)" strings in your array.

Comment: @vadian See the last sentence of my answer. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't get convert an `NSURL` to a file path using the `absoluteString` method. You need to use the `path` method.

Change:

```
let plistpath = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: paths[0]).appendingPathComponent("myplist9.plist")!.absoluteString
```

to:

```
let plistpath = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: paths[0]).appendingPathComponent("myplist9.plist")!.path
```

And since you are using Swift 3, use `URL`, not `NSURL`.

```
let plistpath = URL(fileURLWithPath: paths[0]).appendingPathComponent("myplist9.plist")!.path
```

Or you can use the `NSDictionary write(to:atomically:)` method that takes a `URL`.